# Правильная пагинация в Django

Tags: python, django, pagination

Имеется сущность Задачи. В CBV **TasksCls** выполнена пагинация.

```
'''views.py'''
class TasksCls(View):
    def get(self, request):
        tasks = Task.objects.select_related('id_person').all()
        paginator = Paginator(tasks, 10)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        page = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        count = tasks.count()
        type = 'Все задачи'
        return render(request, 'rootApp/tasks/tasks.html', context={'tasks': page, 'count': count, 'type': type,})
```

Пагинация устроена таким образом, что сначала мы выбираем **все** задачи из таблицы и затем разделяем их на страницы. Это круто, когда задач мало, но если их **гипотетически** будет 1000000? Будет большая нагрузка на БД. Подскажите пожалуйста как грамотно сделать пагинацию?

Comment: у в tasks будет только queryset, на этом этапе django не делает запрос, а вот уже в paginator будет сделан запрос с limit 10 и из базы селектнется только 10 записей... PS поправьте меня кто-то, если я неправ...

Comment: @Jack_oS всё так

Comment: @andreymal а есть какие-то инструменты для отслеживания, чтоб увидеть воочию, в какой строке и сколько сделано запросов к бд, не знаете?

Comment: @Jack_oS [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar)? Хотя конкретную строку не показывает, но запросы таки показывает

Answer (score 1):

Через django-debug-toolbar проверил, как идут запросы, и убедился в том, что выбираются только то количество записей, которое указано в пагинаторе.
@Jack_oS был прав, благодарю!